# How to share SASS variables across multiple files without using the deprecated @import rule?

Tags: sass

***tl;dr:*** **Is there any way to share a set of global variables across multiple files without manually importing them into every file and without using the @import rule?**

---

I used to use @import in a central index.scss file to make some variables available to all other modules imported below also in that file.

Like this:

*index.scss*

```scss
@import "variables";
@import "cards";
@import "buttons";
```

*_variables.scss*

```scss
$primaryColor: lightgreen;
$accentColor: deepskyblue;
```

*_cards.scss*

```scss
.card {
  background-color: $primaryColor;
}
```

*_buttons.scss*

```scss
.cta {
  border-color: $accentColor;
}
```

Referring to variables like `$primaryColor` in a module different from where the variable had originally been defined worked, and I didn't have to import the `_variables.scss` file everywhere I need to have them available.

### Using @use

Since the announcement of the [deprecation of the @import rule](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import), I've been trying to migrate to the `@use` rule. But, the setup I had no longer works.

**I've tried modifying my index file like this:**

*index.scss*

```scss
@use "variables" as *;
@use "cards";
@use "buttons";
```

But, referencing a variable like `$accentColor` inside the `_cards.scss` module, for instance, no longer works.

The only way I've found to make this work so far is to manually import the `_variables.scss` file with `@use` into every module where I access those global variables. However, this is cumbersome and I'd like to avoid it.

Is there any way to share a set of global variables across multiple files without manually importing them into every file and without using the @import rule?

Thank you so much in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>@import</strike>`@use "variables"` in your main style sheet file `application.scss`. See [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65144403/rails-scss-global-variables)